# Get all data from an Oracle DB request

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I want to create a general function in c# for sql requests at my oracle db.
I want to save all columns to strings. I tried to use the `reader.GetString()`method but an exception is thrown, saying it is unconvertable...
How can I make a function which does that ?
`string [] request (OracleConnection con, String Table, String condition, String columns, String sort){
    //The magic code
    return "A string-array with all information";
}`

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the Item property on DBReader?  Also, this method is a serious security risk -- using a condition string instead of params invites sql injection.

```
    public string[] Request(IDBConnection conn, string table, string condition, string columns, string sort)
    {
        List<string> output = new List<string>();
        string[] cols = columns.Split(',');
        string sql = string.Format("select * from {0} etc", table);
        using (IDBCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(conn, sql))
        {
            conn.Open();
            IDBReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                foreach (string col in cols)
                {
                    object field = reader.Item[col];
                    output.Add(field.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        return output.ToArray();
    }
```